# Stored Procedure as Create Table proxy?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, stored-procedures, security

With SQL Server it was my understanding, I thought, that you could elevate a users permissions with specific constraints.

For example, you need a user to create a specific table object in a specific schema. Rather than giving them wholesale create table permission, you could wrap the create table in a stored procedure and give them access to only that. In this way they would be constrained to only creating the object as specified within the procedure and not have any direct create table permission on the database... at least I know it works this way with Select, Insert, Update, Delete. The Create Table statement in the Stored Procedure throws the Permission Denied error.

Am I mistaken or just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it should be working how you think.  Below is an example proving this:

```
-- create the dummy login
create login TestLogin1
with password = 'p@$$w0rd';
go

use TestDB;
go

-- create the test user
create user TestUser1
for login TestLogin1;
go

-- create the proc to create a table
create procedure dbo.CreateTableProc
as

    create table dbo.SomeTestTable(id int);

go

-- give TestUser1 perms to execute CreateTableProc
grant execute
on dbo.CreateTableProc
to TestUser1;
go


-- execute CreateTableProc under the security context of TestUser1
execute as user = 'TestUser1';
go

exec dbo.CreateTableProc;
go

revert;
go
-- unsuccessful, permission denied
```

> Msg 262, Level 14, State 1, Procedure CreateTableProc, Line 4
>   CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'TestDB'.

```
-- alter the proc to execute under my security context (with CREATE TABLE perms)
alter procedure dbo.CreateTableProc
    with execute as owner
as

    create table dbo.SomeTestTable(id int);

go

-- execute CreateTableProc under the security context of TestUser1
execute as user = 'TestUser1';
go

exec dbo.CreateTableProc;
go

revert;
go
-- successful, table created
```

> Command(s) completed successfully.

In this example, `TestUser1` does not have the permissions to create the table.  We see that when the original version of `CreateTableProc` is called, as the `CREATE TABLE` DDL executes under the security context of `TestUser1`.  But then by modifying the `CreateTableProc` stored procedure definition and including the `WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER` clause, now `TestUser1` can successfully call the proc and create a table because now the `CREATE TABLE` DDL executes under the security context of the owner (my database user, in the `db_owner` role).

Comment: I'd also be careful to use the schema prefix when creating, altering and calling the stored procedure.

Comment: Completely missing the "Execute as owner" I was.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just used OWNER in my example. That can be a few possibilities.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Good point, I've edited/fixed.  A bad habit I need to correct :-)

Comment: Is this solution usable to let the SP create the table in another database without the calling user having permissions, like tempdb for example (where permissions get lost by restarting service that's why I am looking for a workaround to let the login create the table there)?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the EXECUTE AS clause. Making use of this you can have a stored procedure execute under the context of a user that does have the permissions to create the table.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx